# Jquery datepicker beforeShowDay browser inconsistency and update issues

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm having a bit of an issue with jQuery UI Datepicker where I am trying to highlight free days in a given month as determined by an ajax call.

The problem is two-fold -

1. The beforeShowDay only appears to be executing correctly in Chrome, not FF or IE, the free-day class is simply not being added in those browsers.
2. Even in Chrome, when scrolling to the previous month, the free day class is not added until returning to that month, in other words the free days are not highlighted on the first view of that month. This does not appear to be an issue moving forward a month though.

javascript

```
// declare freeDays global
var freeDays = [];

// perform initial json request for free days
fetchFreeDays();

$(document).ready(function()
{

    // fairly standard configuration, importantly containing beforeShowDay and onChangeMonthYear custom methods
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
        altField: '#date_due',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        onChangeMonthYear: fetchFreeDays,
        firstDay: 1 // rows starts on Monday
    });
});

// query for free days in datepicker
function fetchFreeDays(year, month)
{
    var start_date = '';

    // if a month and year were supplied, build a start_date in yyyy-mm-dd format
    if (year != undefined && month != undefined) {
      start_date = year +'-';
      start_date += month +'-';
      start_date += '01';
    }

    $.getJSON("ajax.todos.php?start_date="+ start_date, function(data){
         $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            freeDays.push(value.freeDate); // add this date to the freeDays array
        });
    });
}

// runs for every day displayed in datepicker, adds class and tooltip if matched to days in freeDays array
function highlightDays(date)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < freeDays.length; i++) {
      if (new Date(freeDays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
         return [true, 'free-day', 'no to-do items due']; // [0] = true | false if this day is selectable, [1] = class to add, [2] = tooltip to display
      }
    }

    return [true, ''];
}
```

php

```
// ajax.todos.php
$i = 0; // counter prevents infinite loop
$cutoff = '61'; // limit on timespan (in days)
$result = array();

// if date is provided, use it, otherwise default to today
$start_date = (!empty($start_date)) ? mysql_real_escape_string($start_date) : date('Y-m-d');
$check_date = $start_date;
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date +$cutoff days")); // never retrieve more than 2 months

while ($check_date != $end_date)
{
    // check if any incomplete todos exist on this date
    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM " . DB_TODOS . " WHERE date_due = '$check_date'"), 0) == 0)
    {
        $result[] = array('freeDate' => $check_date);
    }

    // +1 day to the check date
    $check_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$check_date +1 day"));

    // break from loop if its looking like an infinite loop
    $i++;
    if ($i > $cutoff) break;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

css

```
/* override free days background in jquery ui datepicker */
.free-day {
  background: #2e9500;
}

.free-day a {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

I wrote a tutorial about this a couple of months ago which is might have some extra info, which is [here](http://stevethomas.com.au/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ajax-request-to-highlight-days-from-mysql.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fetchFreeDays()` is asynchronous, so it is possible that `$("#datepicker").datepicker()` finished executeing before you have populated your `freeDays` array, therefore you don't see anything when the page first renders.

Try putting `$("#datepicker").datepicker()` inside your `$.getJSON`s callback function.

Comment: Still not quite there... 

i've been having trouble implementing the callback on getJSON. 

Now i've tried switching to $.ajax with async: false option, and this seems to resolve the issue of switching months before the free days array is populated, but I still can not get beforeShowDays working in FF or IE.

I have put $('#datepicker').datepicker() within the ajax success: callback.

Comment: In firebug I can see the request and response which both look fine, so it appears the problem is with highlightDays. Is there any reason why the toString line would be treated differently across browsers?